# IQueryable with stored precedure

Tags: linq-to-sql

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SP_GET_RESEARCH_SITES 
AS 
   SELECT
      s.SITE_ID, Site_NAme,
      s.PHONE, s.FAX, s.EMAIL_ID, s.IS_ACTIVE,
      LOCATION_ID, LOCATION_NAME,
      (select FIRST_NAME  from VCT_CONTACTS where CONTACT_ID in
          (select spd.ADMINISTRATOR_ID 
           from VCT_SPONSOR_SITE_PRO_LINKING spl 
           join VCT_SITE_PROTOCOL_DETAILS spd on spl.PR_SPONSOR_ID = spd.PR_SPONSOR_ID
           where spl.LOCATION_ID = sl.LOCATION_ID and SPL.SITE_ID=s.SITE_ID)
      ) as FIRSTNAME,
      (select MIDDLE_NAME  from VCT_CONTACTS where CONTACT_ID in
          (select spd.ADMINISTRATOR_ID 
           from VCT_SPONSOR_SITE_PRO_LINKING spl 
           join VCT_SITE_PROTOCOL_DETAILS spd on spl.PR_SPONSOR_ID = spd.PR_SPONSOR_ID 
           where spl.LOCATION_ID = sl.LOCATION_ID and SPL.SITE_ID=s.SITE_ID)
      ) as MIDDLENAME,
      (select LAST_NAME  from VCT_CONTACTS where CONTACT_ID in
          (select spd.ADMINISTRATOR_ID 
           from VCT_SPONSOR_SITE_PRO_LINKING spl 
           join VCT_SITE_PROTOCOL_DETAILS spd on spl.PR_SPONSOR_ID = spd.PR_SPONSOR_ID 
           where spl.LOCATION_ID = sl.LOCATION_ID and SPL.SITE_ID=s.SITE_ID)
      ) as LASTNAME
   FROM
      VCT_SITES s 
   left join VCT_SITE_LOCATIONS sl on s.SITE_ID = sl.SITE_ID
```

This is my stored procedure which returns a result set. Now I have to use this stored procedure in Linq to apply some `WHERE` condition for search like firstname, lastname etc.

How to use this stored procedure in linq with additional where clauses?

Answer (score 0):

If you used sqlmetal to generate your linq2sql entities, re-run it with the /sprocs option to include stored procedures. You should then have a function on your datacontext called SP_GET_RESEARCH_SITES that will call the stored procedure and return an entityset.

Unfortunately, I don't know how to set this option when generating your linq2sql within Visual Studio, but I'm sure the option is there somewhere :)

Answer (score 0):

A stored procedure is produral code that might happen to give a table as it's resultset, however you can't then add a where clause on to the end of it.  If you chnage your stored procedure to a table valued function, you can then treat it like a table and adding any where, sort, top and skip will append the SQL on the end of the function call, resulting in the SQL server doing the filtering and a more efficient execution.